# How do I implement a variant version of the insert function in an binary search tree?

Tags: c++, data-structures, recursive-datastructures

I am trying to implement the insert function in my bst.template file. I haven't implemented anything important as I am confused on what to do. The insert function is supposed to, Add the item to this binary search tree as long as it is not already present, Return false if item is already in the tree and Return true if item is actually added to the tree. Here's what I've gotten so far.

```cpp
    #include "bst.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
/**
    * Add the item to this binary search tree as long as it
    * is not already present.
    * Return false if item is already  in the tree.
    * Return true if item is actually added to the tree.
    */
template <class T>
bool binary_search_tree<T>::insert(const T &item) {
    if(item )
}

/* 
 * the target value removed -> return true
 * if not -> return false
 */
template <class Item>
bool bst_remove(binary_tree_node<Item>*& root_ptr, const Item& target) {
binary_tree_node<Item> *oldroot_ptr;

        if (root_ptr == NULL)
        {   
       return false;
        }

        if (target < root_ptr->data( ))
        {   
       return bst_remove(root_ptr->left( ), target);
        }

        if (target > root_ptr->data( ))
        {   
       return bst_remove(root_ptr->right( ), target);
        }

        if (root_ptr->left( ) == NULL)
        {   
       oldroot_ptr = root_ptr;
       root_ptr = root_ptr->right( );
       delete oldroot_ptr;
       return true;
        }

        bst_remove_max(root_ptr->left( ), root_ptr->data( ));
        return true;
}

template <class Item>
void bst_remove_max(binary_tree_node<Item>*& root_ptr, Item& removed) {
binary_tree_node<Item> *oldroot_ptr;

        assert(root_ptr != NULL);

        if (root_ptr->right( ) != NULL)
       bst_remove_max(root_ptr->right( ), removed);
        else
        {
       removed = root_ptr->data( );
       oldroot_ptr = root_ptr;
       root_ptr = root_ptr->left( );
       delete oldroot_ptr;
        }
 }

template <class T>
bool binary_search_tree<T>::remove(const T &item) {
    return bst_remove(root, item);
}


template <class T>
binary_tree_node<T> *binary_search_tree<T>::search(const T &key) const {
    binary_tree_node<T> *p = root;
    while(p != NULL && p->data() != key) {
        if(key < p->data())
            p = p->left();
        else
            p = p->right();
    }
}


template <class T>
binary_search_tree<T>::~binary_search_tree() {
    tree_clear(root);
}



/**
 * return the depth of the tree if the tree is balanced.
 * Return -2 if not. Return -1 if it is an empty tree.
 */
template <class T>
int check_balanced(binary_tree_node<T> *root) {
    if(root == NULL)
        return  -1;
    else {
        int ibl = check_balanced(root->left());
        if(ibl == -2)
            return -2;
        int ibr = check_balanced(root->right());
        if(ibr == -2)
            return -2;
        if(abs(ibr-ibl) > 1)
            return -2;
        if(ibr > ibl)
            return ibr+1;
        else
            return  ibl+1;
    }
}


/**
    * return the depth of the tree if the tree is balanced.
    * Return -2 if not.
    */
template <class T>
int  binary_search_tree<T>::is_balanced() {
    return check_balanced(root);
}

template <class T>
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &out, const binary_tree_node<T> *root) {
    if(root != NULL) {
        out << "[";
        out << root->left() << " ";
        out << root->data();
        out << " " << root->right();
        out << "]";
    }
    return out;
}



template <class T>
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &out, const binary_search_tree<T> &tree) {
    out << tree.root;
    return out;
}
```

Here's the header file

```cpp
#ifndef BST_H
#define BST_H

#include "bintree.h"
#include <iostream>


template <class T>
class binary_search_tree {

public:
    binary_search_tree() {
        root = NULL;
    }

    /**
     * Search for the key in this binary search tree.
     * Return a node containing the key, if found.
     * Return null if not found.
     */
    binary_tree_node<T>* search(const T& key) const;

    /**
     * Add the item to this binary search tree as long as it
     * is not already present.
     * Return false if item is already  in the tree.
     * Return true if item is actually added to the tree.
     */
    bool insert(const T& item);


    /**
     * Remove the item from the tree.
     * Return true if the item was actually removed.
     * Return false if the item was not in the tree to begin with.
     */
    bool remove(const T& item);



    ~binary_search_tree();


    /**
     * return the depth of the tree if the tree is balanced.
     * Return -2 if not.
     */
    int is_balanced();

    template <class S>
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const binary_search_tree<S>& tree);

    binary_tree_node<T>* get_root() { return root; }


private:
    binary_tree_node<T>* root;
};


template <class T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const binary_tree_node<T>* root);

/**
 * return the depth of the tree rooted at root if the tree is balanced.
 * Return -2 if not.
 */
template <class T>
int check_balanced(binary_tree_node<T>* root);


template <class Item>
bool bst_remove(
    binary_tree_node<Item>*& root_ptr,
    const Item& target
);
// Precondition: root_ptr is a root pointer of a binary search tree (or may
// be NULL for the empty tree).
// Postcondition: If target was in the tree, then one copy of target has been
// removed, root_ptr now points to the root of the new (smaller) binary
// search tree, and the function returns true. Otherwise, if target was not
// in the tree, then the tree is unchanged, and the function returns false.

template <class Item>
void bst_remove_max(
    binary_tree_node<Item>*& root_ptr,
    Item& removed
);
// Precondition: root_ptr is a root pointer of a non-empty binary search
// tree.
// Postcondition: The largest item in the binary search tree has been
// removed, and root_ptr now points to the root of the new (smaller) binary
// search tree. The reference parameter, removed, has been set to a copy
// of the removed item.



#include "bst.template"


#endif // BST_H
```

Here my binary tree template file

```cpp
// FILE: bintree.template
// IMPLEMENTS: The binary_tree node class (see bintree.h for documentation). 
#include <cassert>    // Provides assert
#include <cstdlib>   // Provides NULL, std::size_t
#include <iomanip>    // Provides std::setw
#include <iostream>   // Provides std::cout


    template<class Process, class BTNode>
    void inorder(Process f, BTNode *node_ptr)
    // Library facilities used: cstdlib
    {
        if (node_ptr != NULL) {
            inorder(f, node_ptr->left());
            f(node_ptr->data());
            inorder(f, node_ptr->right());
        }
    }

    template<class Process, class BTNode>
    void postorder(Process f, BTNode *node_ptr)
    // Library facilities used: cstdlib
    {
        if (node_ptr != NULL) {
            postorder(f, node_ptr->left());
            postorder(f, node_ptr->right());
            f(node_ptr->data());
        }
    }

    template<class Process, class BTNode>
    void preorder(Process f, BTNode *node_ptr)
    // Library facilities used: cstdlib
    {
        if (node_ptr != NULL) {
            f(node_ptr->data());
            preorder(f, node_ptr->left());
            preorder(f, node_ptr->right());
        }
    }

    template<class Item, class SizeType>
    void print(binary_tree_node <Item> *node_ptr, SizeType depth)
    // Library facilities used: iomanip, iostream, stdlib
    {
        if (node_ptr != NULL) {
            print(node_ptr->right(), depth + 1);
            std::cout << std::setw(4 * depth) << ""; // Indent 4*depth spaces.
            std::cout << node_ptr->data() << std::endl;
            print(node_ptr->left(), depth + 1);
        }
    }

    template<class Item>
    void tree_clear(binary_tree_node <Item> *&root_ptr)
    // Library facilities used: cstdlib
    {
        binary_tree_node<Item> *child;
        if (root_ptr != NULL) {
            child = root_ptr->left();
            tree_clear(child);
            child = root_ptr->right();
            tree_clear(child);
            delete root_ptr;
            root_ptr = NULL;
        }
    }

    template<class Item>
    binary_tree_node <Item> *tree_copy(const binary_tree_node <Item> *root_ptr)
    // Library facilities used: cstdlib
    {
        binary_tree_node<Item> *l_ptr;
        binary_tree_node<Item> *r_ptr;

        if (root_ptr == NULL)
            return NULL;
        else {
            l_ptr = tree_copy(root_ptr->left());
            r_ptr = tree_copy(root_ptr->right());
            return
                    new binary_tree_node<Item>(root_ptr->data(), l_ptr, r_ptr);
        }
    }

    template<class Item>
    size_t tree_size(const binary_tree_node <Item> *node_ptr)
    // Library facilities used: cstdlib
    {
        if (node_ptr == NULL)
            return 0;
        else
            return
                    1 + tree_size(node_ptr->left()) + tree_size(node_ptr->right());
    }
```

Here is the binary tree header

```cpp
// FILE: bintree.h (part of the namespace main_savitch_10)
// PROVIDES: A template class for a node in a binary tree and functions for 
// manipulating binary trees. The template parameter is the type of data in
// each node.
// 
// TYPEDEF for the binary_tree_node<Item> template class:
//   Each node of the tree contains a piece of data and pointers to its
//   children. The type of the data (binary_tree_node<Item>::value_type) is
//   the Item type from the template parameter. The type may be any of the C++
//   built-in types (int, char, etc.), or a class with a default constructor,
//   and an assignment operator.
//
// CONSTRUCTOR for the binary_tree_node<Item> class:
//   binary_tree_node(
//       const item& init_data = Item( ),
//       binary_tree_node<Item>* init_left = NULL,
//       binary_tree_node<Item>* init_right = NULL
//   )
//     Postcondition: The new node has its data equal to init_data,
//     and it's child pointers equal to init_left and init_right.
//
// MEMBER FUNCTIONS for the binary_tree_node<Item> class:
//   const item& data( ) const      <----- const version
//   and
//   Item& data( )                  <----- non-const version
//     Postcondition: The return value is a reference to the data from
//     this binary_tree_node.
//
//   const binary_tree_node* left( ) const  <----- const version
//   and
//   binary_tree_node* left( )              <----- non-const version
//   and
//   const binary_tree_node* right( ) const <----- const version
//   and
//   binary_tree_node* right( )             <----- non-const version
//     Postcondition: The return value is a pointer to the left or right child
//     (which will be NULL if there is no child).
//
//   void set_data(const Item& new_data)
//     Postcondition: The binary_tree_node now contains the specified new data.
//
//   void set_left(binary_tree_node* new_link)
//   and
//   void set_right(binary_tree_node* new_link)
//     Postcondition: The binary_tree_node now contains the specified new link
//     to a child.
//
//   bool is_leaf( )
//     Postcondition: The return value is true if the node is a leaf;
//     otherwise the return value is false.
//
// NON-MEMBER FUNCTIONS to maniplulate binary tree nodes:
//   tempate <class Process, class BTNode>
//   void inorder(Process f, BTNode* node_ptr)
//     Precondition: node_ptr is a pointer to a node in a binary tree (or
//     node_ptr may be NULL to indicate the empty tree).
//     Postcondition: If node_ptr is non-NULL, then the function f has been
//     applied to the contents of *node_ptr and all of its descendants, using
//     an in-order traversal.
//     Note: BTNode may be a binary_tree_node or a const binary tree node.
//     Process is the type of a function f that may be called with a single
//     Item argument (using the Item type from the node).
//
//   tempate <class Process, class BTNode>
//   void postorder(Process f, BTNode* node_ptr)
//      Same as the in-order function, except with a post-order traversal.
//
//   tempate <class Process, class BTNode>
//   void preorder(Process f, BTNode* node_ptr)
//      Same as the in-order function, except with a pre-order traversal.
//
//   template <class Item, class SizeType>
//   void print(const binary_tree_node<Item>* node_ptr, SizeType depth)
//     Precondition: node_ptr is a pointer to a node in a binary tree (or
//     node_ptr may be NULL to indicate the empty tree). If the pointer is
//     not NULL, then depth is the depth of the node pointed to by node_ptr.
//     Postcondition: If node_ptr is non-NULL, then the contents of *node_ptr
//     and all its descendants have been written to cout with the << operator,
//     using a backward in-order traversal. Each node is indented four times
//     its depth.
//
//   template <class Item>
//   void tree_clear(binary_tree_node<Item>*& root_ptr)
//     Precondition: root_ptr is the root pointer of a binary tree (which may
//     be NULL for the empty tree).
//     Postcondition: All nodes at the root or below have been returned to the
//     heap, and root_ptr has been set to NULL.
//
//   template <class Item>
//   binary_tree_node<Item>* tree_copy(const binary_tree_node<Item>* root_ptr)
//     Precondition: root_ptr is the root pointer of a binary tree (which may
//     be NULL for the empty tree).
//     Postcondition: A copy of the binary tree has been made, and the return
//     value is a pointer to the root of this copy.
//
//   template <class Item>
//   size_t tree_size(const binary_tree_node<Item>* node_ptr)
//     Precondition: node_ptr is a pointer to a node in a binary tree (or
//     node_ptr may be NULL to indicate the empty tree).
//     Postcondition: The return value is the number of nodes in the tree.

#ifndef BINTREE_H
#define BINTREE_H
#include <cstdlib>  // Provides NULL and size_t


template <class Item>
class binary_tree_node
{
public:
    // TYPEDEF
    typedef Item value_type;
    // CONSTRUCTOR
    binary_tree_node(
        const Item& init_data = Item(),
        binary_tree_node* init_left = NULL,
        binary_tree_node* init_right = NULL
    )
    {
        data_field = init_data;
        left_field = init_left;
        right_field = init_right;
    }
    // MODIFICATION MEMBER FUNCTIONS
    Item& data() { return data_field; }
    binary_tree_node*& left() { return left_field; }
    binary_tree_node*& right() { return right_field; }
    void set_data(const Item& new_data) { data_field = new_data; }
    void set_left(binary_tree_node* new_left) { left_field = new_left; }
    void set_right(binary_tree_node* new_right) { right_field = new_right; }
    // CONST MEMBER FUNCTIONS
    const Item& data() const { return data_field; }
    const binary_tree_node* left() const { return left_field; }
    const binary_tree_node* right() const { return right_field; }
    bool is_leaf() const
    {
        return (left_field == NULL) && (right_field == NULL);
    }
private:
    Item data_field;
    binary_tree_node* left_field;
    binary_tree_node* right_field;
};

// NON-MEMBER FUNCTIONS for the binary_tree_node<Item>:
template <class Process, class BTNode>
void inorder(Process f, BTNode* node_ptr);

template <class Process, class BTNode>
void preorder(Process f, BTNode* node_ptr);

template <class Process, class BTNode>
void postorder(Process f, BTNode* node_ptr);

template <class Item, class SizeType>
void print(binary_tree_node<Item>* node_ptr, SizeType depth);

template <class Item>
void tree_clear(binary_tree_node<Item>*& root_ptr);

template <class Item>
binary_tree_node<Item>* tree_copy(const binary_tree_node<Item>* root_ptr);

template <class Item>
std::size_t tree_size(const binary_tree_node<Item>* node_ptr);


#include "bintree.template"

#endif // BINTREE_H
```

Here is my test file

```cpp
#include <string>
#include "bst.h"
using namespace std;

int rnd() {
    return rand() % 10000;
}

int main() {
    binary_search_tree<string> bst;
    cout << bst << endl;
    bst.insert("baker");
    cout << bst << endl;

    // making sure the output operator was working properly.
    bst.get_root()->set_left(new binary_tree_node<string>("able"));
    cout << bst << endl;
    bst.get_root()->set_right(new binary_tree_node<string>("charlie"));
    cout << bst << endl;

    bst.insert("arthur");
    print(bst.get_root(), 0);
    cout << endl;

    string data[] = { "able", "baker", "charlie", "dog", "easy", "fox", "george" };
    int size = 7;
    binary_search_tree<string> bst1;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        bst1.insert(data[i]);
        cout << bst1 << endl;
    }
    cout << "balanced? " << bst1.is_balanced() << endl << endl;;

    string data2[] = { "dog", "baker", "able", "fox", "charlie",  "george", "easy" };
    binary_search_tree<string> bst2;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        bst2.insert(data2[i]);
        cout << bst2 << endl;
    }
    print(bst2.get_root(), 0);
    cout << "balanced? " << bst2.is_balanced() << endl << endl;

    binary_search_tree<int> bst3;
    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
        bst3.insert(rnd());
    }
    cout << bst3 << endl;
    cout << "balanced? " << bst3.is_balanced() << endl << endl;

    cout << "remove " << bst2.remove("able") << endl;
    cout << bst2 << endl;
    cout << "remove " << bst2.remove("baker") << endl;
    cout << bst2 << endl;
    cout << "remove " << bst2.remove("fox") << endl;
    cout << bst2 << endl;
    print(bst2.get_root(), 0);

}
```

Looking at my book only confused me as it was dealing with nodes, not bools.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a helper function for insert which also passes the node of the tree.

bool insert(item, node)

The declaration of the private function.

```
template <class Item>

bool bst_insert(binary_tree_node<Item>*& root_ptr, const Item& target) ;
```

Algorithm

- Check if the root_ptr is null, Allocate a node and set the root_ptr
  to target;
- If target == root_ptr data , then return false
- else If the target < root_ptr, call bst_insert(&root_ptr->left, target)
- else If the target > root_prt, call bst_insert(&root_prt->right, target)

Comment: I would like to do that, however, I can't change the code from its original state as the teacher wants it this way. sorry for the confusion.